# Dynamically create nested dicts using strings from a list

Tags: python, json, dictionary, nested

I would like create a nested dictionary (== javascript object) based on an existing array.

For instance:

```
input_array =["hello", "how", "are", "you", "?"]
output_object = 
  { "hello":
    { "how":
      { "are":
        { "you":
          { "?": {}
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

In JavaScript, the solution would be something like:

```
for( var i = 0; i < input_array.length; i++ ) {
   output_object[ input_array[i] ] = {};
   output_object = output_object[ input_array[i] ]
};
```

Comment: you could do it recursively I suppose. I'm curious what the application of this is.

Comment: Objects in javascript == dicts in python. A "python object" is a _very_ different concept. Also I should note that there's no need to add "Python:" in the title since the tag automatically identifies this as a python question. I've rolled back your edit, hope this clears things up :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Very similarly:

```
d = d2 = {}
for i in input_array:
     d2[i] = {}
     d2 = d2[i]

d
# {'hello': {'how': {'are': {'you': {'?': {}}}}}}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use recursion:

```
input_array =["hello", "how", "are", "you", "?"]
def to_dict(d):
  return {d[0]:{} if not d[1:] else to_dict(d[1:])}

output_object = to_dict(input_array)
```

Output:

```
{'hello': {'how': {'are': {'you': {'?': {}}}}}}
```

Answer (score 1):

Using  recursive function:

```
>>> def custom_json(array):
    if not array:
        return {}
    else:
        key = array.pop(0)
        return {key : custom_json(array)}
```

---

**Output:**

```
>>> input_array =["hello", "how", "are", "you", "?"]
>>> custom_json(input_array)
{'hello': {'how': {'are': {'you': {'?': {}}}}}}
```